# please what is etc

Tags: wireless, power-management

so i using ubuntu for the first time my wifi keep disconnecting for no good reason,it has to do with power management. so i search here and i keep on seeing

`sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wireless`

`sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`

but the command dont work in my terminal. what was the etc in code ?

error
`bash: cd: /etc/pm/power.d: No such file or directory`

Comment: Are you talking what is `/etc/` ?  If so, that is the folder.  If you are getting errors there is a possibility that the other folders of `pm` or `power.d` or `sleep.d` don't exist.

Comment: Please provide the actual error message that you're getting

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy  i updated the question

Comment: @Terrance  i updated the question

Comment: `wireless` is the filename.  The `/` is the indicator between folders and files.  Folders list first.  So, the folders are `/etc/pm/power.d` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d`.  You might need to create the folders before performing the lines.  `sudo mkdir -p /etc/pm/power.d` and `sudo mkdir -p /etc/pm/sleep.d`

Comment: @Terrance make it an answer. That's  probably the issue here. `/etc/pm/sleep.d` doesn't exist

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Done.  =)

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/pm/sleep.d` or `/etc/pm/power.d` are part of the folder or directory structure of where the file `wireless` is located.   The `/` is the separator for the folders and files.

The error(s) that you are getting is probably because the folders are missing from the `/etc` folder that it is trying to create the `wireless` file in.  To correct this, create the missing folders.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/pm/sleep.d
sudo mkdir -p /etc/pm/power.d
```

Then the commands of

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wireless
sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

should work just fine.

Hope this helps!